# How to identify the begin and end of an incoming call in Android?

Tags: android

I'm developing an application which should:

- Start when incoming call begins.
- End as soon as the call has ended.

More specifically, I don't want the application to begin while the phone is ringing, but when the actual **conversation** is begins (aka, the user has accepted the incoming call).

Does anyone know how to do this? And how to catch these events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadcast Receiver will help you. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)'s the official google developer page on it.

[Here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html) is a small tutorial on the same.

Comment: I don't understand yet how to catch the events I want. Where is it in your second example?

Comment: All you basically need is a [Broadcast Receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). The code right in the end of the tutorial gives you just that.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is provided by the [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html).

You should create a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) which listens for [ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED). When you declare it in your AndroidManifest.xml it will spawn your service/activity. 
When you are spawned it's very likely that the phone is currently just in the ringing state. So you have to register for further changes of the PhoneState via [TelephonyManager.listen()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#listen%28android.telephony.PhoneStateListener,%20int%29). This way you will notice when the phone got hooked off and also when it goes back to idle.

Don't forget to request the [READ_PHONE_STATE permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_PHONE_STATE).

Comment: May you provide me an example?

Comment: An example for the BroadcastReceiver for the TelephoneState may be found [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html). For the state listener try [this](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/62.html) one. You just have to combine them.

Comment: I saw the first article already, @Anand S gave me that link. The second one doesn't describe the way how to  identify the begin and end of an incoming call. Am I wrong?